# WordPress show current page submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have tried to search for this, but I think I'm phrasing the question wrong. What I would like to do is have a submenu appear if a user is viewing that page. Kind of similar to a drop down menu, but instead of on a hover effect, I'd like it to show if you're on the current page, perhaps using the `.current-menu-item` function?

This is the code I have currently:

```
.header-menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.header-menu li {
    background: url("images/arrow.png") no-repeat left center;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition:background-position .3s ease-in;  
    -moz-transition:background-position .3s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:background-position .3s ease-in;  
    transition:background-position .3s ease-in; 
}

.header-menu li:hover {
    background: rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8) url("images/arrow-hover.png") no-repeat left center;
}

.header-menu li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.header-menu ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.header-menu .current-menu-item {
    background: rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8) url("images/arrow-hover.png") no-repeat right center;
}
```

I honestly can't think of a way to pull it off, it's kind of like an if/else statement for CSS, which I really wish existed right now. Thanks though, for any help! I'm completely willing to use JQuery if it would get the job done.

**EDIT**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghnd4ae3/)

Comment: Can you make a Codepen or JSFiddle with your HTML structure in it, too? Then, someone could fork it and provide a more complete answer.

Comment: Does this work? .header-menu .current-menu-item ul.sub-menu { display:block;}

Comment: Well, I'm using WordPress, I didn't manually write the HTML code for the menu, but I can just copy the source if it would help.

Comment: @jacobroufa I added the fiddle, as you requested.

Comment: @gopalraju I think it does! Also it overlaps everything that comes after the menu, how would I nest it within the menu? I feel like that should be easy to do, but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
.header-menu .current-menu-item ul.sub-menu { 
 display:block;
}
```

and

```
.header-menu .current-menu-item{
 height:auto
}
```

to remove the overlap.

Fidddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ghnd4ae3/2/